# LTSpice Double Edge flip-flop not working

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, ltspice, flipflop

I'm an absolute beginner with LTSpice; my first test circuit uses two D flip-flops:
I checked the waveform and found that the D flip-flop is not working properly

Am I doing something wrong, or is LTSpice doing something wrong?

Contents of flipflops.asc file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE -640 -64 -736 -64
WIRE -400 -64 -480 -64
WIRE -144 -64 -256 -64
WIRE -64 -64 -80 -64
WIRE -144 -32 -208 -32
WIRE -640 -16 -720 -16
WIRE 64 0 32 0
WIRE -64 16 -64 -64
WIRE -32 16 -64 16
WIRE -16 16 -32 16
WIRE -32 32 -64 32
WIRE -16 32 -32 32
WIRE -208 64 -208 32
WIRE -208 64 -256 64
WIRE -144 64 -208 64
WIRE -64 64 -64 32
WIRE -64 64 -80 64
WIRE -144 96 -256 96
WIRE -736 160 -736 -64
WIRE -640 160 -736 160
WIRE -400 160 -480 160
WIRE -720 208 -720 -16
WIRE -704 208 -720 208
WIRE -720 336 -720 208
WIRE -720 336 -736 336
WIRE -400 336 -720 336
FLAG 64 0 Vout
IOPIN 64 0 Out
FLAG -256 -64 A
IOPIN -256 -64 In
FLAG -256 64 S
IOPIN -256 64 In
FLAG -256 96 B
IOPIN -256 96 In
FLAG -400 -64 A
IOPIN -400 -64 Out
FLAG -400 160 B
IOPIN -400 160 Out
FLAG -400 336 S
IOPIN -400 336 Out
FLAG -816 -64 0
FLAG -816 336 0
FLAG -736 -64 Vin
SYMBOL Digital\\and -112 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL Digital\\and -112 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\or 0 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\inv -272 32 R270
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL Digital\\dflop -560 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName A5
SYMBOL Digital\\dflop -560 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL voltage -720 336 R90
WINDOW 0 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0 5n 5n 25m 50m)
SYMBOL voltage -720 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -98 30 VTop 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0 5n 5n 15m 30m)
SYMBOL Digital\\inv -704 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName A7
TEXT -192 240 Left 2 !.tran 160m
```

netlist

```
A1 0 A 0 N002 0 0 N001 0 AND
A2 0 S 0 B 0 0 N003 0 AND
A3 0 0 N001 N003 0 0 Vout 0 OR
A4 S 0 0 0 0 N002 0 0 BUF
A5 Vin 0 S 0 0 0 A 0 DFLOP
A6 Vin 0 P001 0 0 0 B 0 DFLOP
V1 S 0 PULSE(0 5 0 5n 5n 25m 50m)
V2 Vin 0 PULSE(0 5 0 5n 5n 15m 30m)
A7 S 0 0 0 0 P001 0 0 BUF
.tran 320m
.backanno
.end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what is going wrong?  It seems to be working as expected for me.  If you're a beginner, then I highly recommend reading the LTspice built-in help (shortcut key `F1`).  More specifically, the page titled [A. Special Functions](https://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceHelp.chm/html/A-device.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you have a model attached to the part, check the netlist to see if there is a model for the A parts, if there isn't then and one. If this came from the LT spice librarys you may still need to add a model. Another thing you can do is right click on the part and look though the properties to see if there is a model (usually a file or path listed)

Comment: I just edited the question and attached the netlist, it looks like there's no model, how can i slove it?

Comment: but i find there is a model path on the window after i right click A part

Comment: LTspice A-devices don't need model definitions, but their default parameters usually do need to be adjusted.  My guess is that in @neuron42 's case that they are expecting all the A-devices to automatically work at 5V since that is what the input sources are set to.  `Vhigh` defaults to 1V, so each device must be right-click edited to add `Vhigh=5` to all of the `Value` fields.